# pyrogram: filenames of documents or videos files from topic of a supergroup is not printed

Tags: python, pyrogram

I try to extract filenames from a topic of supergroup. I try in this way

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(
    name="@Peter_LongX",
    api_id=27*******,
    api_hash="b5*******************",
    phone_number="+393*******",
    password="********" or None
)

group_id = -1001867911973
topic_id = 692
msg_file_dict = {}

with app:
    for message in app.get_chat_history(group_id, limit=5):
        print(f"Message Link: {message.link}")
        print(f"Message ID: {message.id}")
        
        if message.link and str(topic_id) in message.link:
            print("Topic ID found in message link")
            
            if message.video or message.document.mime_type.startswith("video"):
                print("Video or video document found")
                
                msg_id = message.id
                file_name = message.video.file_name or f"VID_{message.id}_{message.video.file_unique_id}.{message.video.mime_type.split('/')[-1]}"
                msg_file_dict[msg_id] = file_name

print(msg_file_dict.keys()) # List of Message ID
print(msg_file_dict.values()) # List of File Name
```

ERRORS

1. It show me the last message links / message ids of entire supergroup and not the last message links / ids of that specific topic. In my context I set up to extract filenames and message links/ids from topic that is `692` - this because from web telegram I see this url : `https://web.telegram.org/a/#-1867911973_692` - however it doesn't print the names of the documents, even if they belong to the supergroup
2. I have a topic with documents, rar files or videos but it doesn't print the filenames of messages links that have documents

Any idea to solve ?

From console I see something like that

```
PS C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\script\messagge_id_telegram> python getmsg.py
Message Link: https://t.me/lasoff...../223390
Message ID: 223390
Message Link: https://t.me/lasoff...../223389
Message ID: 223389
```

but I expect something like this

```
PS C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\script\messagge_id_telegram> python getmsg.py
enter code here
Message Link: https://t.me/lasoff...../223390
Message ID: 223390

Filename: Fondazione_1x10.mp4
Message Link: https://t.me/lasoff...../223389
Message ID: 223389
```

For example `Message Link: https://t.me/lasoff...../223390` should be it might not have a name because maybe it's a sticker or an emojii
Additional question: Do you have any idea how you could print the results from a specific range of dates, for example from July 1st to August 1st 2023?

**EDIT**: as quamrana suggested I tried to get the filenames printed, but still nothing changes, they are not returned when these are there. To do this I change this part of code

```
    if message.link and str(topic_id) in message.link:
        print("Topic ID found in message link")
```

with this

```
if message.link and str(topic_id) in message.link and (message.video or message.document.mime_type.startswith("video")):
    print("Topic ID found in message link")
    print("Video or video document found")
    msg_id = message.id
    file_name = message.video.file_name or f"VID_{message.id}_{message.video.file_unique_id}.{message.video.mime_type.split('/')[-1]}"
    msg_file_dict[msg_id] = file_name
```

Comment: In your actual output from the console, why don't you see any lines like: `"Topic ID found in message link"`? Also in the output you expect, why do you expect: `Filename: ...` when there is no `print()` which could output that?

Comment: @quamrana I have now updated the question, the problem is the filenames are not returned anyway (when they exist, for example if they are videos in mp4 or mkv)

Comment: You're doing `limit=5`.  If there were no messages on topic 692 in the last 5 group messages for the group, then you won't see anything.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, I also extended it to 500 but it doesn't change, because it only returns the message ids and in any case those of the supergroup, not those of the specific topic I requested. Look at this picture to make yourself understood : https://imgur.com/VmNlx7h.png - For example, the code should print the name of the video "Fondazione _1x10.mp4" but it doesn't even do it for the supergroup, and one of the mistakes that is made is that of not even considering the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message links returned by get_chat_history() do not actually contain the topic ID - they follow a format like https://t.me/lasoff...../223390. ↗ Telegram constructs these links based on the chat ID and message ID only.

**Solution to error 1:**

To get messages for a specific topic, we need to use get_discussion_replies(). This method allows passing the ID of the topic starter message, and will return only messages in that topic thread.

**Solution to error 2:**

you have a 'if condition' in your code that never satisfies.

```
if message.link and str(topic_id) in message.link:
```

the `str(topic_id) in message.link` part is never True, because your links don't contain topic_id in the link like you see on the web version url.

the corrected code will be like this:

```
group_id = -1001867911973
topic_id = 692
msg_file_dict = {}

async def main():
    async with app:
        async for message in app.get_discussion_replies(chat_id=group_id,  message_id=topic_id):
            print(f"Message ID: {message.id}")

            if message.video or (message.document and message.document.mime_type.startswith("video")):
                file = message.video or message.document
                print("Video or video document found")

                msg_id = message.id
                file_name = file.file_name or f"VID_{message.id}_{file.file_unique_id}.{file.mime_type.split('/')[-1]}"
                print(file_name)
                msg_file_dict[msg_id] = file_name
            print()

app.run(main())
print(msg_file_dict.keys())  # List of Message ID
print(msg_file_dict.values())  # List of File Name
```

Comment: mm.. Is it possible to print the original filename of the video or document as well?  I see only this in console
`Message ID: 223340`,

`Message ID: 223339
Video or video document found`,

`Message ID: 223338
Video or video document found`

but no original file name is printed after "Video or video document found". For example this `Message ID: 223339` is this link `https://t.me/lasoffittadownloads/661/223389` and the original file name is `Ergo Proxy - 1x23 - Emissario - 1080p by stress.mkv` but is not printed

Comment: @PeterLong I edited the answer. so it will print filename if it founds any.

Comment: any idea to solve also this correlated problem? Look [HERE](https://play.tg-drive.eu.org/?m=https://n0.tg-drive.eu.org/cc92ff8b9b2d90c25653c47f247214) 
 before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77010163/setting-the-datetime-filter-gives-me-a-flood-problem