# Setting the DATETIME filter gives me a flood problem

Tags: python, pyrogram

With this code I can print message ID and filenames into results.txt and **I have not** flood problems. Only problem is that it doesn't print strings between 27-28 august 2023 but it prints all strings.

```
import time
from pyrogram import Client
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

app = Client(
    name="@Peter_LongX",
    api_id=*******,
    api_hash="b**********************",
    phone_number="+3*****",
    password="" or None
)

group_id = -1001867911973
topic_id = 664
msg_file_dict = {}

start_date = datetime(2023, 8, 27)
end_date = datetime(2023, 8, 28)


async def main():
    async with app:
        processed_messages = 0  # Initialize the counter
        async for message in app.get_discussion_replies(chat_id=group_id, message_id=topic_id):
            print(f"Message ID: {message.id}")
            message_date = message.date

            if start_date <= message_date <= end_date:  # Check if the message date is within the specified range
                print(f"Message ID: {message.id}")

            file_name = None  # Declare the variable outside the if statement

            if message.video or (message.document and (message.document.mime_type.endswith("rar") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("zip") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("pdf") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("epub") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("cbr"))):
                file = message.video or message.document
                print("Video or rar/zip/pdf/epub/cbr file found")

                msg_id = message.id
                file_name = file.file_name or f"VID_{message.id}_{file.file_unique_id}.{file.mime_type.split('/')[-1]}"
                print(file_name)
                msg_file_dict[msg_id] = file_name
            print()

            # Appending results to the text file with utf-8 encoding
            with open("results.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                if file_name:
                    file.write(f"Message ID: {message.id}\n")
                    file.write(f"File Name: {file_name}\n")
                    file.write("\n")

            processed_messages += 1  # Increment the counter

            if processed_messages % 40 == 0:
                time.sleep(15)  # Pause for 15 seconds after every 40 messages

app.run(main())
```

So, I thought I'd modify the code a bit so that I can only print strings that are between Aug 27-28. Indeed, in this way, I print strings within those dates.. but, unlike before, now the terminal gives me a FLOOD problem. I don't understand why if I didn't get this error before

```
[previous code]


async def main():
    async with app:
        processed_messages = 0  # Initialize the counter
        async for message in app.get_discussion_replies(chat_id=group_id, message_id=topic_id):
            message_date = message.date
            
            if start_date <= message_date <= end_date:  # Check if the message date is within the specified range
                print(f"Message ID: {message.id}")
                
                file_name = None  # Initialize the variable
                
                if message.video or (message.document and (message.document.mime_type.endswith("rar") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("zip") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("pdf") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("epub") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("cbr"))):
                    file = message.video or message.document
                    print("Video or rar/zip/pdf/epub/cbr file found")
                    
                    msg_id = message.id
                    file_name = file.file_name or f"VID_{message.id}_{file.file_unique_id}.{file.mime_type.split('/')[-1]}"
                    print(file_name)
                    msg_file_dict[msg_id] = file_name
                    
                    # Appending results to the text file with utf-8 encoding
                    with open("results.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                        file.write(f"Message ID: {msg_id}\n")
                        file.write(f"File Name: {file_name}\n")
                        file.write("\n")
                    
                    processed_messages += 1  # Increment the counter

                    if processed_messages % 40 == 0:
                        time.sleep(15)  # Pause for 15 seconds after every 40 messages

app.run(main())
```

The error in second code is this

```
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.flood_420.FloodWait: Telegram says: [420 FLOOD_WAIT_X] - A wait of 15 seconds is required (caused by "messages.GetReplies")
```

Please look at the difference between the 2 behaviors, I don't understand why introducing dates as a filter now gives me a flood error when it didn't before. 
[HERE](https://play.tg-drive.eu.org/?m=https://n0.tg-drive.eu.org/cc92ff8b9b2d90c25653c47f247214) here you can see the difference between running the first code vs the second code
In my opinion, but I could be wrong, perhaps it is necessary to implement some code to manage the logic of the datetime intervals because if the logic of the simple listing does not give me flood problems because introducing datetime filter then there is something that produces the flood error

Answer (score 0):

Floodwait happens because you retreive mesages without a sleep. the if condition you used for checking date of the messages prevents the sleep to be executed.

**the solution:**

you should put this part of code outside of if condition:

```
processed_messages += 1  # Increment the counter

if processed_messages % 40 == 0:
    time.sleep(15)  # Pause for 15 seconds after every 40 messages
```

also put a condition to check if messages are older than 27 august and break the loop. you don't need to go further when you reached 26 august.

so the updated code will be:

```
async def main():
    async with app:
        processed_messages = 0  # Initialize the counter
        async for message in app.get_discussion_replies(chat_id=group_id, message_id=topic_id):
            message_date = message.date
            
            if start_date <= message_date <= end_date:  # Check if the message date is within the specified range
                print(f"Message ID: {message.id}")
                
                file_name = None  # Initialize the variable
                
                if message.video or (message.document and (message.document.mime_type.endswith("rar") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("zip") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("pdf") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("epub") or message.document.mime_type.endswith("cbr"))):
                    file = message.video or message.document
                    print("Video or rar/zip/pdf/epub/cbr file found")
                    
                    msg_id = message.id
                    file_name = file.file_name or f"VID_{message.id}_{file.file_unique_id}.{file.mime_type.split('/')[-1]}"
                    print(file_name)
                    msg_file_dict[msg_id] = file_name
                    
                    # Appending results to the text file with utf-8 encoding
                    with open("results.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                        file.write(f"Message ID: {msg_id}\n")
                        file.write(f"File Name: {file_name}\n")
                        file.write("\n")
            
            elif message_date <= start_date:
                break

            processed_messages += 1  # Increment the counter

            if processed_messages % 40 == 0:
                        time.sleep(15)  # Pause for 15 seconds after every 40 messages

app.run(main())
```